# Why does Visual Studio 2017 keep changing my public static statements to "public" after I change any aspect of any object on a form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, static, public

I've posted my code. Every single time I change anything on my this form in my Windows Forms App in C#, it changes my "public static" changes at the end to just "public" and then it adds "this." to every single reference to them. My code seems to run fine after I edit it again, but this is really annoying. I just wanted to make sure I'm not missing something or taking a poor approach to this.

The reason I am using public static statements is because I am modifying some Textboxes and a DataGridView object on my main form from other forms - i.e. looking up customer info from a database in one form and then entering the data on the main form to write up an order, and taking shopping cart information from a WebBrowser control on one form and putting it into a DataGridView object on another form. If this isn't how to accomplish populating forms from another form please tell me how and be as specific as possible as I am quite new to C#. Sorry if I've posted too much code - this is almost everything from my form1.cs file and I didn't know what (if anything) that I have here is causing the problem. The relevant "public static" statements are at the end.

(AFTER I WROTE THIS - I looked up another thread where someone said that forms are supposed to be a "specific instantiation" and that is why the developer environment keeps taking out the "static"). That being the case... HELP!! I do not understand how to change the values on one form from another form and I absolutely need to do so. - this code works, but I guess it's bad practice? - Completely lost and need very specific instructions to make this work)

Thanks in advance!!!

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class frmMain
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.cmdSendEmail = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.cmdExit = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.cmdLookup = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.txtTransactionNumber = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.cmdEdit = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.cmdBrowse = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.groupBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.cmdCustomer = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.txtNotes = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        txtZip = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        txtCountry = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        txtState = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        txtCity = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        txtAddress = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        txtName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        txtPayPalEmail = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        txtEmail = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        txtPhone = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        txtLast = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        txtFirst = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        grdOrderItems = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.Qty = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.Description = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.UnitPrice = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.ExtPrice = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.SCode = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.Options1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.Options2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.groupBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.lblSubTotal = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblTotal = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.txtTax = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.txtShipping = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.txtShippingMethod = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.cmdTaxLookup = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.lstShipping = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.cmdBrowser = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.groupBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.cmdSendRequest = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.cmdClear = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.cmdSave = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.cmdPrint = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.cmdSavePrintEmail = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.groupBox1.SuspendLayout();
        this.groupBox2.SuspendLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(grdOrderItems)).BeginInit();
        this.groupBox3.SuspendLayout();
        this.groupBox4.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // cmdLookup
        // 
        this.cmdLookup.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(88, 15);
        this.cmdLookup.Name = "cmdLookup";
        this.cmdLookup.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(197, 33);
        this.cmdLookup.TabIndex = 3;
        this.cmdLookup.Text = "Look up order to attach request to";
        this.cmdLookup.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // txtTransactionNumber
        // 
        this.txtTransactionNumber.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(91, 57);
        this.txtTransactionNumber.Name = "txtTransactionNumber";
        this.txtTransactionNumber.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(158, 20);
        this.txtTransactionNumber.TabIndex = 5;
        // 
        // cmdEdit
        // 
        this.cmdEdit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(260, 57);
        this.cmdEdit.Name = "cmdEdit";
        this.cmdEdit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(87, 30);
        this.cmdEdit.TabIndex = 6;
        this.cmdEdit.Text = "Edit";
        this.cmdEdit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // 
        // groupBox1
        // 
        this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(438, 125);
        this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
        this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(345, 56);
        this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 10;
        this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // cmdBrowse
        // 
        this.cmdBrowse.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 139);
        this.cmdBrowse.Name = "cmdBrowse";
        this.cmdBrowse.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(220, 22);
        this.cmdBrowse.TabIndex = 11;
        this.cmdBrowse.Text = "Browse Unpaid Payment Requests";
        this.cmdBrowse.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // groupBox2
        // 
        this.groupBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.cmdCustomer);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.txtNotes);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(txtZip);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(txtCountry);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(txtState);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(txtCity);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(txtAddress);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(txtName);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(txtPayPalEmail);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(txtEmail);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(txtPhone);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(txtLast);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(txtFirst);
        this.groupBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 168);
        this.groupBox2.Name = "groupBox2";
        this.groupBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(749, 264);
        this.groupBox2.TabIndex = 12;
        this.groupBox2.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox2.Text = "Customer Information";
        this.groupBox2.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.groupBox2_Enter);
        // 
        // label21
        // 
        this.label21.AutoSize = true;
        this.label21.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(186, 215);
        this.label21.Name = "label21";
        this.label21.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 13);
        this.label21.TabIndex = 24;
        this.label21.Text = "Zip:";
        // 
        // cmdCustomer
        // 
        this.cmdCustomer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(657, 136);
        this.cmdCustomer.Name = "cmdCustomer";
        this.cmdCustomer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(86, 69);
        this.cmdCustomer.TabIndex = 23;
        this.cmdCustomer.Text = "Load Customer Info from Prior Order";
        this.cmdCustomer.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.cmdCustomer.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.cmdCustomer_Click);
        // 
        // txtNotes
        // 
        this.txtNotes.AcceptsReturn = true;
        this.txtNotes.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(404, 136);
        this.txtNotes.Multiline = true;
        this.txtNotes.Name = "txtNotes";
        this.txtNotes.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical;
        this.txtNotes.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(247, 122);
        this.txtNotes.TabIndex = 19;
        // 
        // txtZip
        // 
        txtZip.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(211, 212);
        txtZip.Name = "txtZip";
        txtZip.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(99, 20);
        txtZip.TabIndex = 25;
        txtZip.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtZip_TextChanged);
        // 
        // txtCountry
        // 
        txtCountry.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 237);
        txtCountry.Name = "txtCountry";
        txtCountry.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(238, 20);
        txtCountry.TabIndex = 22;
        txtCountry.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtCountry_TextChanged);
        // 
        // txtState
        // 
        txtState.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 210);
        txtState.Name = "txtState";
        txtState.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(108, 20);
        txtState.TabIndex = 21;
        txtState.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtState_TextChanged);
        // 
        // txtCity
        // 
        txtCity.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 185);
        txtCity.Name = "txtCity";
        txtCity.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(238, 20);
        txtCity.TabIndex = 20;
        txtCity.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtCity_TextChanged);
        // 
        // txtAddress
        // 
        txtAddress.AcceptsReturn = true;
        txtAddress.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 92);
        txtAddress.Multiline = true;
        txtAddress.Name = "txtAddress";
        txtAddress.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical;
        txtAddress.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(236, 87);
        txtAddress.TabIndex = 18;
        txtAddress.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtAddress_TextChanged);
        // 
        // txtName
        // 
        txtName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 68);
        txtName.Name = "txtName";
        txtName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(238, 20);
        txtName.TabIndex = 17;
        txtName.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtName_TextChanged);
        // 
        // txtPayPalEmail
        // 
        txtPayPalEmail.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(405, 98);
        txtPayPalEmail.Name = "txtPayPalEmail";
        txtPayPalEmail.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(203, 20);
        txtPayPalEmail.TabIndex = 16;
        // 
        // txtEmail
        // 
        txtEmail.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(404, 65);
        txtEmail.Name = "txtEmail";
        txtEmail.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(204, 20);
        txtEmail.TabIndex = 15;
        // 
        // txtPhone
        // 
        txtPhone.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(405, 39);
        txtPhone.Name = "txtPhone";
        txtPhone.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(203, 20);
        txtPhone.TabIndex = 14;
        txtPhone.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtPhone_TextChanged);
        // 
        // txtLast
        // 
        txtLast.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(189, 39);
        txtLast.Name = "txtLast";
        txtLast.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 20);
        txtLast.TabIndex = 13;
        txtLast.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtLast_TextChanged);
        // 
        // txtFirst
        // 
        txtFirst.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 39);
        txtFirst.Name = "txtFirst";
        txtFirst.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(84, 20);
        txtFirst.TabIndex = 12;
        txtFirst.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtFirst_TextChanged);

        // grdOrderItems
        // 
        grdOrderItems.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
        grdOrderItems.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        grdOrderItems.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.Qty,
        this.Description,
        this.UnitPrice,
        this.ExtPrice,
        this.SCode,
        this.Options1,
        this.Options2});
        grdOrderItems.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 19);
        grdOrderItems.Name = "grdOrderItems";
        grdOrderItems.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(732, 81);
        grdOrderItems.TabIndex = 0;
        grdOrderItems.CellValueChanged += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(grdOrderItems_CellValueChanged);
        grdOrderItems.RowsAdded += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler(this.grdOrderItems_RowsAdded);
        // 
        // Qty
        // 
        this.Qty.HeaderText = "Qty";
        this.Qty.Name = "Qty";
        this.Qty.Width = 48;
        // 
        // Description
        // 
        this.Description.HeaderText = "Description";
        this.Description.Name = "Description";
        this.Description.Width = 85;
        // 
        // UnitPrice
        // 
        this.UnitPrice.HeaderText = "Unit Price";
        this.UnitPrice.Name = "UnitPrice";
        this.UnitPrice.Width = 78;
        // 
        // ExtPrice
        // 
        this.ExtPrice.HeaderText = "Ext. Price3";
        this.ExtPrice.Name = "ExtPrice";
        this.ExtPrice.ReadOnly = true;
        this.ExtPrice.Width = 83;
        // 
        // SCode
        // 
        this.SCode.HeaderText = "S-Code";
        this.SCode.Name = "SCode";
        this.SCode.Width = 67;
        // 
        // Options1
        // 
        this.Options1.HeaderText = "Options1";
        this.Options1.Name = "Options1";
        this.Options1.Width = 74;
        // 
        // Options2
        // 
        this.Options2.HeaderText = "Options2";
        this.Options2.Name = "Options2";
        this.Options2.Width = 74;
        // 
        // groupBox3
        // 
        this.groupBox3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
        this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(this.checkBox1);
        this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(this.cmdApplyTaxRate);
        this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(this.txtTaxRate);
        this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(this.lblSubTotal);
        this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(this.lblTotal);
        this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(this.txtTax);
        this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(this.txtShipping);
        this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(this.txtShippingMethod);
        this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(this.cmdTaxLookup);
        this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(this.lstShipping);
        this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(this.cmdBrowser);
        this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(this.groupBox4);
        this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(grdOrderItems);
        this.groupBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 443);
        this.groupBox3.Name = "groupBox3";
        this.groupBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(749, 242);
        this.groupBox3.TabIndex = 13;
        this.groupBox3.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox3.Text = "Order Information";
        // 
        // checkBox1
        // 
        this.checkBox1.AutoSize = true;
        this.checkBox1.Checked = true;
        this.checkBox1.CheckState = System.Windows.Forms.CheckState.Checked;
        this.checkBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(253, 224);
        this.checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1";
        this.checkBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(257, 17);
        this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 21;
        this.checkBox1.Text = "Automatically Apply Tax Rate with order changes";
        this.checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // cmdApplyTaxRate
        // 
        this.cmdApplyTaxRate.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(313, 194);
        this.cmdApplyTaxRate.Name = "cmdApplyTaxRate";
        this.cmdApplyTaxRate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(126, 24);
        this.cmdApplyTaxRate.TabIndex = 20;
        this.cmdApplyTaxRate.Text = "Apply Tax Rate";
        this.cmdApplyTaxRate.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // txtTaxRate
        // 
        this.txtTaxRate.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(186, 198);
        this.txtTaxRate.Name = "txtTaxRate";
        this.txtTaxRate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(101, 20);
        this.txtTaxRate.TabIndex = 19;
        // 
        // lblSubTotal
        // 
        this.lblSubTotal.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblSubTotal.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(571, 128);
        this.lblSubTotal.Name = "lblSubTotal";
        this.lblSubTotal.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(13, 13);
        this.lblSubTotal.TabIndex = 18;
        this.lblSubTotal.Text = "$";
        // 
        // lblTotal
        // 
        this.lblTotal.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblTotal.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(571, 210);
        this.lblTotal.Name = "lblTotal";
        this.lblTotal.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(13, 13);
        this.lblTotal.TabIndex = 17;
        this.lblTotal.Text = "$";
        // 
        // txtTax
        // 
        this.txtTax.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(561, 177);
        this.txtTax.Name = "txtTax";
        this.txtTax.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(182, 20);
        this.txtTax.TabIndex = 16;
        // 
        // txtShipping
        // 
        this.txtShipping.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(561, 149);
        this.txtShipping.Name = "txtShipping";
        this.txtShipping.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(182, 20);
        this.txtShipping.TabIndex = 15;
        // 
        // txtShippingMethod
        // 
        this.txtShippingMethod.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(559, 105);
        this.txtShippingMethod.Name = "txtShippingMethod";
        this.txtShippingMethod.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(182, 20);
        this.txtShippingMethod.TabIndex = 14;
        // 
        // cmdTaxLookup
        // 
        this.cmdTaxLookup.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(138, 218);
        this.cmdTaxLookup.Name = "cmdTaxLookup";
        this.cmdTaxLookup.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(99, 21);
        this.cmdTaxLookup.TabIndex = 13;
        this.cmdTaxLookup.Text = "Lookup Tax Rate";
        this.cmdTaxLookup.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // lstShipping
        // 
        this.lstShipping.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.lstShipping.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(304, 106);
        this.lstShipping.Name = "lstShipping";
        this.lstShipping.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 69);
        this.lstShipping.TabIndex = 5;
        // 
        // cmdBrowser
        // 
        this.cmdBrowser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 106);
        this.cmdBrowser.Name = "cmdBrowser";
        this.cmdBrowser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(164, 21);
        this.cmdBrowser.TabIndex = 2;
        this.cmdBrowser.Text = "Launch Browser Form";
        this.cmdBrowser.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.cmdBrowser.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.cmdBrowser_Click);
        // 
        // groupBox4
        // 
        this.groupBox4.Controls.Add(this.cmdSendRequest);
        this.groupBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 133);
        this.groupBox4.Name = "groupBox4";
        this.groupBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(162, 57);
        this.groupBox4.TabIndex = 1;
        this.groupBox4.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox4.Text = "PayPal";
        // 
        // cmdSendRequest
        // 
        this.cmdSendRequest.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 19);
        this.cmdSendRequest.Name = "cmdSendRequest";
        this.cmdSendRequest.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(131, 32);
        this.cmdSendRequest.TabIndex = 2;
        this.cmdSendRequest.Text = "Send Payment Request";
        this.cmdSendRequest.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.cmdSendRequest.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.cmdSendRequest_Click_1);
        // 
        // cmdClear
        // 
        this.cmdClear.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 696);
        this.cmdClear.Name = "cmdClear";
        this.cmdClear.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(67, 25);
        this.cmdClear.TabIndex = 14;
        this.cmdClear.Text = "Clear";
        this.cmdClear.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // cmdSave
        // 
        this.cmdSave.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(91, 697);
        this.cmdSave.Name = "cmdSave";
        this.cmdSave.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(67, 25);
        this.cmdSave.TabIndex = 15;
        this.cmdSave.Text = "Save";
        this.cmdSave.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // cmdPrint
        // 
        this.cmdPrint.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(164, 697);
        this.cmdPrint.Name = "cmdPrint";
        this.cmdPrint.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(67, 25);
        this.cmdPrint.TabIndex = 16;
        this.cmdPrint.Text = "Print";
        this.cmdPrint.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // cmdSavePrintEmail
        // 
        this.cmdSavePrintEmail.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(393, 694);
        this.cmdSavePrintEmail.Name = "cmdSavePrintEmail";
        this.cmdSavePrintEmail.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(131, 31);
        this.cmdSavePrintEmail.TabIndex = 17;
        this.cmdSavePrintEmail.Text = "Save, Print, and Email";
        this.cmdSavePrintEmail.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // frmMain
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(790, 725);
        this.Controls.Add(this.cmdSavePrintEmail);
        this.Controls.Add(this.cmdPrint);
        this.Controls.Add(this.cmdSave);
        this.Controls.Add(this.cmdClear);
        this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.cmdBrowse);
        this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.optRequestNew);
        this.Controls.Add(this.optRequestShipping);
        this.Controls.Add(this.optRequestAdd);
        this.Controls.Add(this.cmdEdit);
        this.Controls.Add(this.txtTransactionNumber);
        this.Controls.Add(this.cmdLookup);
        this.Controls.Add(this.cmdExit);
        this.Controls.Add(this.cmdSendEmail);
        this.Name = "frmMain";
        this.Text = "PayPal Payment Request Program version C1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox1.PerformLayout();
        this.groupBox2.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox2.PerformLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(grdOrderItems)).EndInit();
        this.groupBox3.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox3.PerformLayout();
        this.groupBox4.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdSendEmail;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdExit;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdLookup;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtTransactionNumber;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdEdit;
    private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdBrowse;
    private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdCustomer;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtNotes;
    private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox4;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdSendRequest;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdBrowser;
    private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdApplyTaxRate;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtTaxRate;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtTax;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtShipping;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtShippingMethod;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdTaxLookup;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lstShipping;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdClear;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdSave;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdPrint;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdSavePrintEmail;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Qty;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Description;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn UnitPrice;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ExtPrice;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn SCode;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Options1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Options2;
    public static System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtEmail;
    public static System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtPhone;
    public static System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtLast;
    public static System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtCountry;
    public static System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtState;
    public static System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtAddress;
    public static System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtPayPalEmail;
    public static System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView grdOrderItems;
    public static System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtZip;
    public static System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtCity;
    public static System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtName;
    public static System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtFirst;
}
```

}

Comment: TL;DR; **never** change a file that has a `.designer.cs` extension. It will be automatically replaced by Visual Studio.

Comment: `static` means that the same value will be used by every instance of that class. You don't normally want that in a Form. There are better ways to pass Form instances around.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the `.designer.cs` file carefully you will notice this little comment

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
```

Basically that part of the code are auto generated by the designer and should never be modified manually.

And yes this is considered bad practice. Firstly the control should be self contained inside the form instead of being a static one. Static just means there will only be one instance across all the forms of the same class.

Direct modification of UI from one form to another is considered anti-pattern as well. You should be making a Data model and have the UI reads the updated data when they are changed. I know this might be a bit challenging for beginners as well for winform.

So if you want to take the shortcut you can expose a public property on the other form and by modifying the property your other form will update the appropriate control.

Edit:
In the other form's code behind (.cs file)

you can do like

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string SelectedUser { get; private set; }
}
```

and then in your main form you would listen to the close event

```
    Form1 other = new Form1();
    other.FormClosed += Other_FormClosed;
    other.Show();
```

...

```
private void Other_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Form1 other = (Form1)sender;
    string selectedUser = other.SelectedUser;

    //do something
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean by "expose a public property on the other form"? For purposes of discussion, let's say I have two forms. One is a main form from which I launch any other forms and one is a data gathering form where the user can look up customers from our database. I want to launch the data gathering form from a command button on the main form and then populate text boxes on the main form with whichever customer the user has chosen. Which form should have a "public property"? How do I make it public, and how exactly do I access that information?

Comment: Alternatively, can you direct me to someplace to read about this "data model" concept? I'm just upgrading a program I wrote years ago in VB6, but I have more of this kind of thing to do in the future. I'd like to understand how to accomplish this as several of my other programs have this same kind of concept - launching forms from a main form to fill in data on the main form. It would be nice if I could figure out how to do this the correct way. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Steve for the help! I'll give that a try. I'm always hesitant to post here because so many people on stackoverflow love to point out what an immense idiot a person is without actually answering a question or coming up with suggestions. I had a feeling I was doing something stupid, which is why I posted it to start with.

Comment: @AlanDenke you could lookup MVC design pattern. Or MVVM design pattern if you are willing to upgrade to WPF/UWP

Comment: That short-cut, by the way, as I'm sure is no surprise to you, works perfectly! Thank you!!! That handled one of my forms - the other one I don't actually want to close when updating - I'm assuming I can "listen" to other events? I want the data to change on a button click.

Comment: No need to answer - I got it to work by changing the forecolor (not sure that was the best choice, but I'll get there) and listening to that event. Anyway, I'm very grateful for the help and for stopping me from continuing on the path I was on.